# Curl request to restore snapshot in elastic search works but the same request in python does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, elasticsearch

I am using aws elastic search and I am restoring some indices to my elastic search to do so I use two approches:

1) I use curl as follows:

```
 curl -XPOST 'xxxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/_snapshot/test/snapshot_4/_restore' -d '{"indices": "movies"}'
```

Which works fine.
Now I am trying to automate the process so I use python to do so and here is my code:

```
from boto.connection import AWSAuthConnection

class ESConnection(AWSAuthConnection):

   def __init__(self, region, **kwargs):
       super(ESConnection, self).__init__(**kwargs)
       self._set_auth_region_name(region)
       self._set_auth_service_name("es")

   def _required_auth_capability(self):
       return ['hmac-v4']

if __name__ == "__main__":

   clientDestination = ESConnection(
        region='us-east-1',
        host=xxxxxxx.es.amazonaws.com',
        aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxx',
        aws_secret_access_key='xxxxx', is_secure=False)


print("Restoring snapshots")

resprestore = clientSource.make_request(method='POST',
                                        path='/_snapshot/test/snapshot_4/_restore',
                                        data='{"indices": "movies"}')
print(resprestore.read())
```

And when I run it I get :

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"snapshot_restore_exception","reason":"[test:snapshot_4/DR01R_WRR2ihiiKe1HgrzA] cannot restore index [movies] because it's open"}],"type":"snapshot_restore_exception","reason":"[test:snapshot_4/DR01R_WRR2ihiiKe1HgrzA] cannot restore index [movies] because it's open"},"status":500}
```

What is the problem? Should I add anyb parameter to the client request? Why the curl works then? Is tehre any parameter I need to add to the python API request?

Comment: Can you show the output you get from the curl query?

Comment: @Val sure here is what I get:  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    38  100    17  100    21      8     10  0:00:02  0:00:01  0:00:01    10{"accepted":true}

Comment: @Val also it is noteworthy that I am able to verify that it works properly by checking Kibana  to see the results restored

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
es = Elasticsearch(host=“127.0.0.1”, port=1234, use_ssl=True, verify_certs=False,connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)
print(es)
```

this should do the magic and connect you to AWS

I'm connecting to 127.0.0.1 because I created a tunnel to my elastic search in AWS 
so in case you are not using tunnel you can use it direct